# Fatal error: Call to a member function register() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter_2.1.3\application\controllers\customer.php on line 30

Tags: php, codeigniter

this is my controller class

```
public function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->load->model('customer_model');


}
public function create()
{

    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'text', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {

    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->view('templates/header');  
    $this->load->view('master/customer');

    }
    else
    {
    $this->customer_model->register();
    //$this->load->view('news/success');
    }
```

}
}

and this is my moodel class

class Customer_model extends CI_model
{

```
public function _construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
}

public function register()
{

    $data = array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),

        'address' => $this->input->post('address')
    );
    return $this->db->insert('registration', $data);
}
```

}

while running codeigniter i'm getting this error

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Customer::$customer_model

Filename: controllers/customer.php

Line Number: 30

Fatal error: Call to a member function register() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter_2.1.3\application\controllers\customer.php on line 30

i'm new to codeigniter any body please tell me why this error is occuring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in controller & model, try changing:

```
public function _construct() {
....
}
```

to

```
public function __construct() { //double underscore
....
}
```